# Spark XML - How to enforce struct type String while loading XML with out specifying schema

Tags: xml, apache-spark

I try to load Dynamic XML file and transform data to dataframe. The exemple of my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <catalog>
  <book id="bk104">
   <title>Oberon</title>
   <code>000010</code>
  </book>
  <book id="bk106">
   <title>Lover</title>
   <code>000030</code>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

Using Scala API:

```
val df = sqlContext.read
   .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
   .option("rowTag", "book")
   .load("books.xml")
```

I try to display the schema of my data frame:

```
root
     |-- title: string (nullable = true)
     |-- price: float (nullable = true)
     |-- code: long (nullable = true)
```

The problem is: the value 000010 (code) is display 10 because Scala API consider it as an Integer.

Are there any solution to read the column "code" as a string to keep value "000010"?
P/s: Because of some contraints in my project, the solution of specify schema is not recommended

```
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .schema(customSchema)
    .load("books.xml")
```

Comment: Did you find any answer for this?

Comment: Currently, this issue is in the discussion here:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/issues/205

Answer (score 0):

When reading XML files the API accepts several options:

**path**: Location of files. Similar to Spark can accept standard Hadoop globbing expressions.

**rowTag**: The row tag of your xml files to treat as a row. For example, in this xml   ..., the appropriate value would be book. Default is ROW. At the moment, rows containing self closing xml tags are not supported.

**samplingRatio**: Sampling ratio for inferring schema (0.0 ~ 1). Default is 1. Possible types are StructType, ArrayType, StringType, LongType, DoubleType, BooleanType, TimestampType and NullType, unless user provides a schema for this.

**excludeAttribute** : Whether you want to exclude attributes in elements or not. Default is false.

**treatEmptyValuesAsNulls** : (DEPRECATED: use nullValue set to "") Whether you want to treat whitespaces as a null value. Default is false
mode: The mode for dealing with corrupt records during parsing. Default is PERMISSIVE.
PERMISSIVE : sets other fields to null when it meets a corrupted record, and puts the malformed string into a new field configured by columnNameOfCorruptRecord. When a schema is set by user, it sets null for extra fields.
DROPMALFORMED : ignores the whole corrupted records.
FAILFAST : throws an exception when it meets corrupted records.

**columnNameOfCorruptRecord**: The name of new field where malformed strings are stored. Default is _corrupt_record.

**attributePrefix**: The prefix for attributes so that we can differentiate attributes and elements. This will be the prefix for field names. Default is _.

**valueTag**: The tag used for the value when there are attributes in the element having no child. Default is _VALUE.

**charset**: Defaults to 'UTF-8' but can be set to other valid charset names

**ignoreSurroundingSpaces**: Defines whether or not surrounding whitespaces from values being read should be skipped. Default is false.

Currently there is **no option** available to explicitly infer schema of certain fields when reading XML files.

Hence, Schema need to be defined explicitly in this case.

source: https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml